# What are the popular SSL stacks used in IoT / embedded devices?

Tags: iot

I'm working on a toolkit that would hopefully make developer's lives a whole lot easier by integrating with the device's SSL stack (not necessarily with its standard APIs, hence this question...)

My first step is to try and understand what are the popular stacks that are used in the IoT and embedded spaces. The point here is to understand what is really used and not just to get a list I can get from Google so your advice and experience is highly appreciated!!

Thanks.

Comment: Be aware of https://iot.stackexchange.com/ I am not sure that this would be on-topic, as it is worded, but you probably ought to be aware of the site. Also, this is very broad - what do you mean by an IoT device?